# Are there N consecutive occurrences of a number in a row/column in a matrix?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, matrix

Take a matrix **A** consisting positive integers, and a single positive integer **N** as input, and determine if there are at least **N** consecutive occurrences of the same number in any row or column in the matrix.

You need only test horizontally and vertically.

#### Test cases

```
N = 1
A = 
1
Result: True
----------------
N = 3
A = 
1 1 1
2 2 3
Result: True
----------------
N = 4
A = 
1 1 1
2 2 3
Result: False
----------------
N = 3
A = 
3 2 3 4 2 1
4 1 4 2 4 2
4 2 3 3 4 1
1 1 2 2 3 4
3 2 3 1 3 1
1 1 2 2 3 4
Result: True
----------------
N = 1
A = 
5 2 3 8
Result: True
----------------
N = 3
111   23  12    6
111   53   2    5
112  555   5  222
Result: False
----------------
N = 2
 4  2  6  2  1  5
 2  3  3  3  3  3
11 34  4  2  9  7
Result: True
```

Explanations are always a good thing :)

Comment: You seem to love matrixes.

Comment: Well, I'm a MATLAB guy... **Mat**rix **Lab**oratory =)

Comment: Is it enough to return a truthy/falsy value?

Comment: @Dennis of course :)

Comment: Annoyingly, because you are a Matlab guy, you make challenges that seem easy in MATLAB but have a slight twist that rule out the obvious solution...

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
;ZjṡƓE€S
```

Takes the matrix as arguments and reads the integer from STDIN.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU65DQIxEMxdxRbgxOvzASKmAiKwHJKcrgFSEgqgAnIaIEaiD2jE7GcHSEhI@87MjnY6zPOx1vV@et2vz8vmfbpt6@NMbVeDi26g5I41O8g5lOK8DB44Ci2Q0QNF/IeLunoYZDDRIBcKce2oalVuWnXH7qNo9w1af2jti9SQZf85kBAACYOAPMJoHsqkKLwwqTG8ppSEp4KIzY8fFvVonU3sTvb4nc2T/uLbdr@iXJBr@QA)

#### How it works

```
;ZjṡƓE€S  Main link. Argument: M (matrix / row array)

 Z        Zip/transpose M.
;         Concatenate the row array with the column array.
  j       Join the rows and columns, separating by M.
    Ɠ     Read an integer n from STDIN.
   ṡ      Split the result to the left into overlapping slices of length 2.
     E€   Test the members of each resulting array for equality.
       S  Take the sum.
```

#### Example run

```
;ZjṡƓE€S  Argument: [[1, 2], [3, 2]]. STDIN: 2

 Z        [[1, 3], [2, 2]]

;         [[1, 2], [3, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2]]

  j       [1, 2, [1, 2], [3, 2], 3, 2, [1, 2], [3, 2], 1, 3, [1, 2], [3, 2], 2, 2]

    Ɠ     2

   ṡ      [[1, 2],             [2, [1, 2]],        [[1, 2], [3, 2]],   [[3, 2], 3],
           [3, 2],             [2, [1, 2]],        [[1, 2], [3, 2]],   [[3, 2], 1],
           [1, 3],             [3, [1, 2]],        [[1, 2], [3, 2]],   [[3, 2], 2],
           [2, 2]                                                                 ]

     E€   [     0,                       0,                       0,             0,
                0,                       0,                       0,             0,
                0,                       0,                       0,             0,
                1                                                                 ]

       S  1
```

Comment: I had the same idea with `;Z`, though in Japt rather than Jelly...

Comment: Now I see why you asked about _truthy/falsy values_. That definition in Jelly was inspired by MATLAB (or MATL) wasn't it?

Comment: No, Jelly uses Python's conditionals internally. The `Ȧ` atom was inspired by MATL though.

Comment: Oh well mine was way too long >.< Right, the `E` builtin was the way to do it. Nice :)

Answer (score 7):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
≤▲mLṁgS+T
```

Takes a 2D array and a number, returns `0` for falsy instances and a positive number for truthy instances.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HnkkfTNuX6PNzZmB6sHfL////oaBMdIx0zIDbUMY3ViTbSMYZBIM/QUMfYRAekwlLHPDb2vxEA)

### Explanation

Husk is a functional language, so the program is just a composition of several functions.

```
≤▲mLṁgS+T
        T  Transpose the array
      S+   and concatenate with original.
           We get a list of the rows and columns of the input array.
    ṁ      Map and concatenate
     g     grouping of equal consecutive elements.
           This gives all consecutive runs on rows and columns.
  mL       Map length over the runs,
 ▲         take the maximum of the results
≤          and see if it's at least the second input.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL, <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
{1∊∊⍷∘⍵¨(⊢,⍪¨)⍺/¨⍳⌈/∊⍵}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE4yrDR91dIFQ7/ZHHTMe9W49tELjUdcinUe9qw6t0HzUu0v/0IpHvZsf9XTog1VtrTVTMHvUu8VYwUjBWMEESBoCSUMwC4aNwTKGYGgEVQdRbwjGSOL//wMA)

Thanks to @MartinEnder and @Zgarb for -2 bytes each (composition removes the need to use `w` and pointless parens)

Alert me if there are any problems and/or bytes to golf. Left argument is **N**, right argument is **A**.

Explanation:

```
{1∊∊⍷∘⍵¨(⊢,⍪¨)⍺/¨⍳⌈/∊⍵}
                     ⍵    - Right argument
                    ∊     - Flatten the array
                 ⍳⌈/      - 1 ... the maximum (inclusive)
              ⍺/¨         - Repeat each item ⍺ (left argument) times.
        (⊢,⍪¨)            - Argument concatenated with their transposes.
    ⍷∘⍵¨                  - Do the patterns occur in ⍵?
   ∊                      - Flatten (since we have a vector of arrays)
 1∊                       - Is 1 a member?
{                     }   - Function brackets
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
t!YdY'wg)>~a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0QxMiVSvTxd064u8f//aGMFIwVjBRMgaWgNpAzBTCC2BjOMwXJAGUMgNIIotVaA6DEEYRSZWC5jLgA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XU6xCkIxDNzzFXESxybNUym8yU9weZSCDwQX3R64@ev1kk5KSHPN3XF5rduz3/q2W@7L/v04zJ@1X669pkaJamJUYUFpI/1fZKrqiDNerDNYh@gSQIMD4z4Z0sLDk7x/mEiwwKcRn8BBJTxBiI@51RxjmDHEImHztMmvcHoER7mWNcc1Zz42ki8).

#### Explanation

A non-square matrix cannot be properly concatenated to its transpose, either vertically or horizontally. So the code concatenates them *diagonally*, by creating a block-diagonal matrix.

The resulting matrix is linearized in column-major order and run-length encoded. The zeros resulting from the block-diagonal concatenation serve to isolate the runs of actual values.

The results from run-length encoding are an array of values and an array of run-lengths. The run-lengths corresponding to non-zero values are kept. The output is `1` if some of those lengths is greater than or equal to the input number, and `0` otherwise.

Let's see the intermediate results to make it clearer. Consider inputs

```
[10 10 10;
 20 20 30]
```

and

```
3
```

The block diagonal matrix containing the input matrix and its transpose (code `t!Yd`) is:

```
10 10 10  0  0
20 20 30  0  0
 0  0  0 10 20
 0  0  0 10 20
 0  0  0 10 30
```

This matrix is implicit linearized in column-major order (down, then across):

```
10 20  0  0  0 10 20  0  0  0 10 30  0  0  0  0  0 10 10 10  0  0 20 20 30
```

Run-length encoding (code `Y'`) gives the following two vectors (shown here as row vectors; actually they are column vectors): vector with values

```
10 20  0 10 20  0 10 30  0 10  0 20 30
```

and vector with run lengths

```
1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 5 3 2 2 1
```

Keeping only the lengths correspoinding to non-zero values (code `wg)`) gives

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1
```

Comparing to see which lengths are greater than or equal to the input number (code `>~`) produces the vector

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Finally, the output should be `true` (shown as `1`) if the above vector contains at least a `true` entry (code `a`). In this case the result is

```
1
```

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, <s>77</s> 70 bytes

```matlab
@(A,N)any(([x y]=runlength([(p=padarray(A,[1 1]))(:);p'(:)]))(!!y)>=N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5BDgIhDLz3Fd2TkHipcJJg3A/wAcKB6K4eDG7Y1cjrsRAPHmY6nU4mfV62@J5qPYtx72RMRQj/wRJsfqXHlG7bXXix2CVeY86xcMoTUpBSHKVZdsxND0ORJ@tknS3GtBoAhxaVgZGHB4UHVKiZCTRSVwzQ3W8XAm7lred@eWr49wP3zv3P@gU)

Explanation:
Since tha matrix only contains non-zero integers we can add a border of 0s around the matrix and compute runlength encoding of the matrix(reshaped to a vector)

```matlab
@(A,N)any(([x y]=runlength([(p=padarray(A,[1 1]))(:);p'(:)]))(!!y)>=N)
                             p=padarray(A,[1 1])                        % add a border of 0s around the matrix 
                            (                   )(:)                    % reshape the matrix to a column vector
                                                     p'(:)              % transpose of the matrix reshaped to a column vector
                           [                        ;     ]             % concatenate two vectors vertically
           [x y]=runlength(                                )            % runlength encoding of the vector[x=count,y=value]
          (                                                 )           % take x,counts.
                                                             (!!y)      % extrect those counts that their valuse aren't 0
      any(                                                        >=N)  % if we have at least a count that is greater than or equal to N
```

Comment: I really like your solutions (not only this one), but they could definitely benefit from some explanations! :) I didn't know Octave had `runlength`... Learn something new everyday...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about `runlength`! Being more focused on Matlab, I didn't remember that existed in Octave

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks, answer updated after waking up!

Comment: @LuisMendo After one of your posts I became aware of a function named `runlength`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 60 bytes

```
{(@^m|[Z,] @^m).map(*.rotor($^n=>$^n-1).map({[==] $_}).any)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtBDoIwFESvMgti@k1tUkrcQNFzSMB0ISsLpLhpkLPXlu5czOS//zLLy72vwXqcRuiwsftgv92D94gHCWsWdhZu/syOFcOk21gXmf9bp3WP4rmTMJOnPdRYjcdtZKxRKKFQxZYtR1NBHhCTMdnkDyujLfMgYd7KlH9LHIrq8AM)

- `@^m` is the input matrix (first argument) and `$^n` is the number of consecutive occurrences to check for (second argument).
- `[Z,] @^m` is the transpose of the input matrix.
- `(@^m | [Z,] @^m)` is an or-junction of the input matrix and its transpose.  The following `map` evaluates to a truthy value if `$^n` consecutive equal values occur in any row of the invocant.  Applied to the input matrix OR its transpose, it evaluates to a truthy value if either the input matrix or its transpose contain `$^n` consecutive equal values in any row; if the transpose meets that condition, that means the input matrix has `$^n` consecutive equal values in one of its columns.
- `*.rotor($^n => $^n - 1)` turns each row into a sequence of `$^n`-element slices.  For example, if `$^n` is 3 and a row is `<1 2 2 2 3>`, this evaluates to `(<1 2 2>, <2 2 2>, <2 2 3>)`.
- `.map({ [==] $_ })` turns each slice into a boolean that indicates whether all elements of the slice are equal.  Continuing the previous example, this becomes `(False, True, False)`.
- `.any` turns that sequence of booleans into an or-junction which is truthy if any of the booleans are true.

The output is a truthy or-junction value which is true if either the input matrix OR its transpose have ANY row where `$^n` consecutive values are equal.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>129</strike> <strike>128</strike> <strike>125</strike> <strike>120</strike> <strike>104</strike> 101 bytes

Huge thanks to @Zachary T, @Stewie Griffin, @Mr. Xcoder, @Rod, @totallyhuman for improving this by a lot.

```python
def f(n,m):
 a=b=c=0;m+=zip(*m)
 for r in m:
  for i in r:b,a=[1,b+1][a==i],i;c=max(c,b)
 return n<=c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYsxDsMgEAR7v4IS4isCuHJyL0EUQIxCAbaQIyX5PDkoU5y0s3N7fM7nXnRrjy2yyAtksU7MoceA11ue8ZsOfsliYnGvrLJUWKaHQalTXT04NBL8LK1xiMlCugXM7s0DeBrW7XzVwsodQztqKiePXIExGiRoWECBtGAWop7pBily3XYnyanRLER6pL79d1aI9gM)

Comment: You don't need a space between `1` and `if`.

Comment: Save four bytes by replacing `a=b;b=0;c=0` with `a=b=c=0`

Comment: (I'm not sure) but I think that you could use `m+zip(*m)` instead `m`on the 4th line, and drop entirely the 1st line, moving the `n<=max()` to the last line as `n<=c`

Comment: [120 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYzBDsIgDIbvPEWPoD3IttO0T4I7ABuRRHAhM5m@PAK7eWjT7//arp/t8Yp93gnu@amDmTVEDGO8UdA7dzwIdPzrV34KQgg2Lw5qODLQZMjShYF7JUjgI4SSNvKV0mhQk5JoznJSmshP6K@2/bVoBIO0bO8UweY1@bjxnXeoVI8d9jiULidUA8o2l2pUXbXVyeK6Y7vQcSdr/blJiPwD "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Instead of `b=b+1` use `b+=1`... Ahh, Ninja'd by @StewieGriffin

Comment: You also don't need the space between `else` and `1`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
cUy)d_ò¦ d_Ê¨V
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Y1V5KWRf8qYgZF/KqFY=&input=W1szLDIsMyw0LDIsMV0sWzQsMSw0LDIsNCwyXSxbNCwyLDMsMyw0LDFdLFsxLDEsMiwyLDMsNF0sWzMsMiwzLDEsMywxXSxbMSwxLDIsMiwzLDRdXQoz)

- 3 bytes saved with some help from ETHproductions.

---

### Explanation

```
    :Implicit input of 2D array U and integer V
c   :Append to U...
Uy  :U transposed.
d   :Check if any of the elements (sub-arrays) in U return true when...
_   :Passed through a function that...
ò   :Partitions the current element by...
¦   :Checking for inequality.
d   :Check if any of the partitions return true when...
_   :Passed through a function that checks if...
Ê   :The length of the current element...
¨V  :Is greater than or equal to V.
    :Implicit output of resulting boolean.
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't see this before posting mine. You could save 2 bytes with `cUy)®ò¦ d_l ¨V\nd`, and another with `cUy)d_ò¦ d_l ¨V`, and then you practically have my (deleted) solution.

Comment: Ha-Ha; great minds ..., @ETHproductions :) I'm shocked I was fastest finger after obarakon beating me all day today! Thanks for those tips, had spotted one already but not the other yet.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60</s> <s>92</s> 91 bytes

```python
def f(n,x):x=[map(str,i)for i in x];print any(`[i]*n`[1:-1]in`x+zip(*x)`for i in sum(x,[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7LCgIxDLz7FT22Gg99@cQvKYUVtNiD3WVdoevPr0lWRCSUZmYyyXTjcGuLmabLNYkkC1R1qKdwP3fyMfSQVWp7kUUuosZj1@cyiHMZZRNyXJYm6MNax1yaunrlTi6rar7zj@ddVghRqSlJDSFoiFEtkrTcY0UIBrBm2iFtkbbgkCTRIaIeHyODGqmk0QLDjENkuSPvv8ar6bpnYvcTQeMUGgxsyIPI0xrPAH/vAT3mk86ggxJsKBsPzWm42ALWcdo9bNEyvQE)

Instead of counting, a list with size `n` (for each element in the matrix) is generated and checked if it's on the matrix

**Without strings, 94 bytes**

```python
lambda n,x:any((e,)*n==l[i:i+n]for l in x+zip(*x)for i in range(len(l)-n+1)for e in sum(x,()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NbsIwEITvPIWPu2R7iH@AIuVJKIcgktaSs0QplUJfPt3dCglarSx75vPYM96uHxf2S9@8LaUdTufWMc37lm8AHeGam6Yc8j5XfOwvkysus5ur7zzCekZ1sjpTy@8dlI6h4AtXtZFOyefXADMBIi7jlPnqeqjpIAuPuLo7wRwZJPAk8wijwCAwUBSkV6IoPcsy5YUpVabPeHOiqGAnzf5lDx9on2T27l@pWhIS9rTRvKikTyYTsqdEkvRPfb3ktNNG29rV3342FqQQrf8rbSW4/AA)

Comment: I think this can give false positives with multidigit numbers.

Comment: @xnor there, fixed

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 59 bytes

```matlab
@(A,N)any({[l,v]=runlength(blkdiag(A,A')(:)),l(v>=0)}{2}>=N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQcNRx08zMa9Sozo6R6cs1raoNC8nNS@9JEMjKSc7JTMxHajAUV1Tw0pTUydHo8zOQLO22qjWztZP83@arUJiXrE1F5efgq2CsTWXI5CKNlYwUjBWMAGShlwKIGCiYAjmAjFMAKQCpAaqwhAIjSDaIAIQMwxBGENFLNC@NLCj/wMA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##bU7LCoMwELz7FXtrAh6axNhHUOoP@APiIW3VlgYLrRWK@O12N4KlUJZNZndmkrmfOttX03RgWZhz277ZULiwL5PHq3VV23QXdnS389U2KMhWnO05Dx3r0zUfBzmmSc6nGhKw7dMENStEGYLgHgGWAYmlcKn@LSO/VDRBhCdSESoIYhsPlOeQIa@cpQZmj6D@YZaftJ@33zgCNaiWEKMBB01PaMJ4aQ1okHKx088xJSLJHMIX6UFFPtkONqiXPJg@).

This uses the same approach as my [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128715/36398) (see explanation there).

Comment: `blkdiag(A,A')`. Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
q~_z+N*e`:e>0=>!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7AuvkrbTys1wSrVzsDWTvH/f2Ou6GhjBSMFYwUTIGkYy6UQbaJgCOYAMYQLkgXJg2UNgbJGEA0gLkSvIQijy8YCAA)

#### Explanation

```
q~    e# Read and eval input.
_z+   e# Append the matrix's transpose to itself.
N*    e# Join with linefeeds to flatten without causing runs across rows.
e`    e# Run-length encode.
:e>   e# Get maximum run (primarily sorted by length).
0=    e# Get its length.
>!    e# Check that it's not greater than the required maximum.
```

Comment: I always wondered why  CJam's RLE gives run-length, then value. Well, it turns out to be useful here :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I guess because that's the way you'd say it "3 a's, 5 b's, 2 c's". I actually find this order useful quite often.

Comment: Actually, Octave's `runlength` function gives outputs in that order too. But somehow I feel the order `value, length` more natural

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16 14</s> 12 bytes

```
Døìvyγ€gM²‹_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v8wNWFiMWX//0TDuMOsdnnOs@KCrGdNwrLigLlf//9bWzFdXQox)

```
Dø           # Duplicate the input and transpose one copy
  ì          # Combine the rows of both matrixes into one array
   vy        #   For each row...
     γ       #     Break into chunks of the same element
      €g     #     get the length of each chunk
        M    #     Get the largest length so far
         ²‹_ #     Check if that is equal to or longer than required
```

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I'm not sure what you mean. That example has 3 consecutive `0`s in the second row, so it should be true.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn If you break up that run [(TIO)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5fCOw2vKKs9tftS0Jt330KZHDTvj//@PjjbWMdQx1jHRMQWSxrE6QL4BEFpCMJBvgCIfy2UMAA) it returns false.

Comment: Doesn't the third command concatenate the transposed rows to the original rows?

Comment: Also, I thought it was supposed to only return true for 3 when there is `[3,3,3]`. I misread the challenge in that case, so I think I'm wrong here.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The first 3 commands will create an array that contains each row and each column as individual elements.

Comment: Ahhh, I misunderstood which command it was too; wow, I apologize. I thought that was direct prepend.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I thought so too, but I guess it prepends each element instead of the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
ŒrFUm2<⁴$ÐḟL
ZÇo³Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCK30Fwjm0eNW1QOT3i4Y74PV9Th9vxDmw@3////PzraUMdQxyBWB0gb6RgDaQMdYx2T2Nj/xgA)

```
ŒrFUm2<⁴$ÐḟL  Helper Link
Œr            Run-length encode
  F           Flatten the whole thing, giving the numbers in the odd indices and the lengths of the runs in the even indices
   U          Reverse
    m2        Take every other element (thus only keeping the run lengths)
         Ðḟ   Discard the elements that are
      <⁴$                                   less than the required run length
           L  And find the length
ZÇo³Ç         Main Link
Z             Zip the matrix
 Ç            Call the helper link on it
   ³Ç         Call the helper link on the original matrix
  o           Are either of these truthy?
```

Returns `0` for false and a non-zero integer for truthy.

Ew, this is bad. And very long. Golfing tips would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

Takes the matrix `m` and the expected number of occurrences `n` in currying syntax `(m)(n)`. Returns a boolean.

```js
m=>n=>[',',`(.\\d+?){${m[0].length-1}}.`].some(s=>m.join`|`.match(`(\\b\\d+)(${s}\\1){${n-1}}\\b`))
```

#### How?

This code is not particularly short, but I wanted to try an approach purely based on regular expressions.

**Conversion of the matrix to a string**

We use `m.join('|')` to transform the 2D-array into a string. This first causes an implicit coercion of the matrix rows to comma-separated strings.

For instance, this input:

```js
[
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 4, 5, 6 ]
]
```

will be transformed into:

```js
"1,2,3|4,5,6"
```

**Row matching**

We look for consecutive occurrences in a row with:

```js
/(\b\d+)(,\1){n-1}\b/
```

This is matching:

- `\b` a word boundary
- `\d+` followed by a number
- `(){n-1}` followed ***n-1*** times by:

  - `,` a comma
  - `\1` followed by our reference: a word boundary + the first number
- `\b` followed by a word boundary

**Column matching**

We look for consecutive occurrences in a column with:

```js
/(\b\d+)((.\d+?){L-1}.\1){n-1}\b/
```

where `L` is the length of a row.

This is matching:

- `\b` a word boundary
- `\d+` followed by a number
- `(){n-1}` followed ***n-1*** times by:

  - `(){L-1}` ***L-1*** times:

    - `.` any character (in effect: either a comma or a pipe)
    - `\d+?` followed by a number (this one must be non-greedy)
  - `.` followed by any character (again: either a comma or a pipe)
  - `\1` followed by our reference: a word boundary + the first number
- `\b` followed by a word boundary

#### Test cases

```js
let f=

m=>n=>[',',`(.\\d+?){${m[0].length-1}}.`].some(s=>m.join`|`.match(`(\\b\\d+)(${s}\\1){${n-1}}\\b`))

console.log(f([
  [ 1 ]
])(1))

console.log(f([
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2, 3 ]
])(3))

console.log(f([
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2, 3 ]
])(4))

console.log(f([
  [ 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1 ],
  [ 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2 ],
  [ 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 ]
])(3))

console.log(f([
  [ 5, 2, 3, 8 ]
])(1))

console.log(f([
  [ 111,  23,  12,   6 ],
  [ 111,  53,   2,   5 ],
  [ 112, 555,   5, 222 ]
])(3))

console.log(f([
  [  4,  2,  6,  2,  1,  5 ],
  [  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3 ],
  [ 11, 34,  4,  2,  9,  7 ]
])(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 58 bytes

```matlab
f=@(A)runlength([A;nan*A](:))
F=@(A,n)max([f(A),f(A')])>=n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDNbsMgDMfP5SmsStVg4mII7RaUabn0JbIc0BK2KR2dkrSaVO3ZM0NarT1MgDE///0h9q@jO7ZT40ZXnBhAhbVEOfaH1qYX0LIKFOha6n94Jr3bDXNARwQZWbQZiaJHx2aJxwjamKxmnZ31GM81v2lmEnu4HQwRAJQGQEUOrO1MjI44EkOEHGNMfBBUKlb9GzVLwnWyGPV06@tNBUCTahY@AmxqqdII7MeyyRfPvBT9Ieza8Da@86q0wYX7sua5EGwbozKIT/fNK09CSeZO1OKpCJPf99AVmG/Yoizi3/NOojghlV2EC1Bn0LfDBekz8l/9Rxg9X66aHFYNHAeyL2EpO7lNXSUlCcva0LDpFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 21 bytes

```
-⊸≢1=⊣≠∘⍷˘∘↕˘⎊0¨⋈⟜⍉∘⊢
```

Anonymous tacit function; takes the number `n` as left argument and the 2D array `a` as right argument. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgLeKKuOKJojE94oqj4omg4oiY4o23y5jiiJjihpXLmOKOijDCqOKLiOKfnOKNieKImOKKogoK4oCiU2hvdyBuIOKGkCAzCuKAolNob3cgYSDihpAgW1sxLDEsMV0sWzIsMiwzXV0KCm4gRiBh)

#### Explanation

So. Many. Modifiers. ○_○

```
-⊸≢1=⊣≠∘⍷˘∘↕˘⎊0¨⋈⟜⍉∘⊢
                      ∘⊢  With the right argument (a),
                 ⋈⟜⍉     pair it with its transpose
                ¨         Apply this function to each of those arrays
     ⊣                    and the original left argument (n):
             ˘              Within each row of the array,
            ↕               get all sublists of length n
          ˘∘                Then, with each of those sublists,
       ≠∘⍷                  uniquify and get the length (1 iff all elements are equal)
              ⎊0           If that function errored because n is too big, use 0 instead
                          We now have a list of two elements, each of which is either
                          an array of integers or a 0
   1=                     Compare each integer to 1 (0 if not equal, 1 if equal)
 ⊸≢                      Is that nested list different from
-                         the same list with each integer negated?
```

If there are no sublists where all items are identical, we'll get a nested list containing only zeros, which remains the same under negation; thus, `≢` will return 0. If there is at least one sublist with identical items, we'll get a nested list that contains a 1 somewhere, which changes under negation; thus, `≢` will return 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
:∩JvøĖ≤fa
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI64oipSnbDuMSW4omkZmEiLCIiLCJbWzMsMiwzLDQsMiwxXSxbNCwxLDQsMiw0LDJdLFs0LDIsMywzLDQsMV0sWzEsMSwyLDIsMCw0XSxbMSwxLDIsMiwzLDRdLFszLDIsMywxLDMsMV0sWzEsMSwyLDIsMyw0XV1cbjMiXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
lambda M,n:(', 0'*n)[5:]in`[map(cmp,l,l[1:])for l in M+zip(*M)]`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LjsMgDDw3X@FboeWwEOgjUj8hX8AiNfuIikQoqlKt2p/P2pCseljJQuOZ8WCnx3i5RjX1p/cpdMPHVwetiA1bC3hbbyK3pnE@nu3QJfY5JBFEsLJxvL/eIICP0G6fPrFNy915@rn48A2yqVaYcfIx3UfGq1W6@ThCz5DkE7NWOidA8oogAizsrRJARVqdtTpr@OqsZJPOXCHonTmVfcWafSVXLYomrl66kvq/D0mdfzcLd3jZVpKZZlHa5XliTEk2hSBkcJoC1Ms5Zc1duWV2/@09V0lAoJcjjwL2lKH4Lw)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 77 bytes

```
#((set(for[I[%(apply map vector %)]i I p(partition %2 1 i)](count(set p))))1)
```

Creates all consecutive partitions `p` of length `N` (symbol `%2`) and counts how many distinct values it has. Then it forms the set of these lengths and returns `1` if it is found from the set and `nil` otherwise. `for` construct was the perfect fit for this, my original attempt used `flatten`, `concat` or something of that short.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>90,84</s> 70 bytes

```
A\n=(~X=occursin("0"^(n-1),[X;0X[1,:]'][:]|>diff.|>sign|>join);~A|~A')
```

(A>0 is exploited.)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJJasMwFIUucwo1XUQCJVge0jTBpt70DAbXBeGhdTBy8NASMNn3DN1kk0O1y56k-lKcmiRI-pbe8Afw12HdFjnf_9wECW-4G44QwiGLKKNN1aaE6jeSayWvCJlyWRG1hrQiLjU2zXhR9yILQGTLeFTZ0gBPeXoAFKA5KiClqW0a0DkYnAvFWU-OQhfngzAG_VnSaYJ_fkyjYMdSvcOth-XLcRxAJGOaUGM4k630cxXZyWZCo4OtUFnBsmFGoB8Quo-oOegsy4sCM8oMuQ0C4RoJLJBs2EWVblLeYLZU_DX_VQX7TxKN7pD_LFy8C1wutjgri6TC7zFvaMrjt6r8wAGZdd526tWbIm_wtvOSPMs6b13mgt66eGJMCCGz38_D2Bi_YDFlhKx2frfzJ-TQNtl08f3UVyjjuK3qXOCTlIbByghCRpfRJAqXkc4uC9b5q9BFzrORrKwQ9qmgVVoTF_5dOekjr-u0atQwriRGqUi0Yb_X3z8)

and a `StatsBase`-based vari:

#### 16+54 bytes

```
using StatsBase
A\n=(~X=any(eachrow(X).|>x->any(rle(x)[2].≥n));~A|~A')
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Dø«δÅγ›ß
```

First input is the matrix \$A\$, second is the integer \$N\$.
Outputs an inverted boolean: `0` for truthy and `1` for falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5fCOQ6vPbTncem7zo4Zdh@f//x8dbaxjpGOsYwIkDWN1ok10DMFsIAbzQHIgWZCcIVDOCKIagwcxxRCE0eRiuYwB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmVBsr6SQmJeioGQPZDxqmwRkVCa4FP13Obzj0OpzWw63ntv8qGHX4fn/df5HA4FhbKyOYayOAoipYwhiRhvpGOkYA4WNsQubQISNQVwdEyAJkjQBKgKxgRjMA8mBZEFyIAOMIKoxeBBTDEEYTQ5uvylYwALJnYZAVUANRjpmID1AninIGFMwB0ibmuoA9RgZIYwAuccM5FKwIojbwBCsRcfYBOx2Sx1zoBbT2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
D         # Duplicate the (implicit) input-matrix
 ø        # Zip/transpose its copy; swapping rows/columns
  «       # Merge it to the input-matrix
          # (we now have a list of all rows and all columns)
          #  e.g. input=[[1,1,1],[2,2,3]] → [[1,1,1],[2,2,3],[1,2],[1,2],[1,3]]
   δ      # Map† over each inner list:
    Åγ    #  Run-length encode it; pushing the list of items and list of lengths
          #  separately to the stack, only leaving the top list of lengths
          #   → [[3],[2,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
       ›  # Check for each inner-most length if it's smaller than the second (implicit)
          # input-integer
        ß # Pop and push the flattened minimum to check if any was falsey
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

† `δ` is technically an 'apply double-vectorized', which also uses the second (implicit) input-integer as argument. It's usually used to create tables from two lists, or to apply a builtin that takes a single argument on each inner item of a list.
In this case, the implicit input-integer is simply ignored since builtin `Åγ` takes no arguments, and `δ` therefore acts as a map. We use this, because map `εÅγ}` is 1 byte longer and map `€Åγ` would also keep the lists of items (so the example above would become `[[3],[1],[2,1],[2,3],[1,1],[1,2],[1,1],[1,2],[1,1],[1,3]]` instead).